# Creating dynamic slider in R Shiny using PLSQL

Tags: r, oracle, plsql, shiny, plsqldeveloper

I want to use a slider so I can adjust the period which I am viewing the data I'm working with.

In my UI component I use the following to create the slider on the UI dashboard:

```
sliderInput("range", "Range:",min = 2009, max = 2021, value = c(2009,2021))
```

This slider correctly appears on my dashboard but I'm not sure how to use this in the sql statement to generate the table that I need. I want to be able to use the value selected with the left side of the slider, and also the value at the right side of the slider. I was hoping to use the following R script to get the left value of the slider but I am getting an error:

```
query_str <- paste0(
  "select * From ", 
  oracle_dataset,
  " where Year >= '",
  input$min,
  "'" 
)

 cat(query_str)
    
    select_data <- dbGetQuery(con, query_str)
```

I am getting this error but I don't know what function to use as I have tried a couple:

```
Warning: Error in paste0: object 'sliderinput' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

Comment: your sliderInput inputId is "range", so you need to refer to input$range, not input$min.  input$range will contain the (current) min and max values of the slider

Comment: Thanks I used remembered to used [] to choose the relevant value of the vector then. i.e. input$range[1]